# Can you obtain audio stream data to the System output device using CoreAudio?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-audio

Is it possible to obtain a stream of audio data arriving at the system output (speakers, headphones, etc.) using CoreAudio or another framework?

**Example:** You're listening to a song on iTunes while watching a YouTube video, all while playing a computer game that makes sounds of its own, all of which are being played through your computer's speakers (Probably terribly annoying).  My app would need to receive the entire mix as streaming data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's at least possible because Audio Hijack can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at a user application's Core Audio or other app framework level.  Some audio output capture/snoop apps may do this with a kernel extension (kext), or perhaps a replacement audio hardware driver.